# Adding new language to Gedit

Tags: gedit

I need to add a new language in Gedit. The problem is, it is included in Gedit menu of languages now, but its syntax is not highlighted and Gedit is not able to indentify the language just from the file suffix.

I've created both .lang file and a XML file describing MIME-TYPE.

```
LANG file - /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/test.lang
MIME-TYPE file - /usr/share/mime/packages/test.xml
```

After creating them I've updated the mime database.

```
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

---

#### Next attempts

1) I've tried even copying `test.xml` file to `/usr/share/mime/applications` folder instead of `/usr/share/mime/packages`, but it had no effect.

2) I've tried to put the mime type into the `/etc/mime.types` as

`text/x-test                 test`

and it had no effect too.

---

#### test.lang

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<language id="test" _name="Test" version="1.0" _section="Source">
    <metadata>
        <property name="mimetypes">text/x-test</property>
        <property name="globs">*.test</property>
        <property name="line-comment-start">//</property>
        <property name="block-comment-start">/*</property>
        <property name="block-comment-end">*/</property>
    </metadata>

    <styles>
       <style id="comment" _name="Comment" map-to="def:comment"/>
       <style id="keyword" _name="Keyword" map-to="def:keyword"/>
    </styles>

    <definitions>
        <context id="if0-comment" style-ref="comment">
          <start>\%{preproc-start}if\b\s*0\b</start>
          <end>\%{preproc-start}(endif|else|elif)\b</end>
          <include>
            <context id="if-in-if0">
              <start>\%{preproc-start}if(n?def)?\b</start>
              <end>\%{preproc-start}endif\b</end>
              <include>
                <context ref="if-in-if0"/>
                <context ref="def:in-comment"/>
              </include>
            </context>
            <context ref="def:in-comment"/>
          </include>
        </context>

        <context id="keywords" style-ref="keyword">
            <keyword>hello</keyword>
            <keyword>hi</keyword>
        </context>

        <!--Main context-->
        <context id="test">
            <include>
                <context ref="if0-comment"/>
                <context ref="keywords"/>
            </include>
        </context>

    </definitions>
</language>
```

#### test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info" >
  <mime-type type="text/x-test">
    <sub-class-of type="text/plain"/>
    <comment xml:lang="en">TEST language document</comment>
    <comment xml:lang="cs">Dokument v jazyce TEST</comment>
    <glob pattern="*.test"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Comment: Your `<definitions>` block lacks the main `<context id=test">` to start with. As per the [docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/lang-tutorial.html) - scroll down to `<definitions>`: _Here we should define a main context, the one we enter at the beginning of the file[ ...] with an id equal to the id of the <language> element_

Comment: @don_crissti I've added the main context, but the problem still lasts :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I've figured it out. According to [GTK lang reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/lang-reference.html) `version` attribute in `<language>` tag should be `2.0`. And it's really working.

So, the proper `<language>` tag is this:

```
<language id="test" _name="Test" version="2.0" _section="Source">
```